# Issue when adding second custom menu to global context

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

```
Issue when adding second custom menu to global context - Unsupported operand types in /app/wp-content/plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(462)
```

I'm working on grabbing a second registered menu and adding it to a header template. I'm using the Timber plugin with Twig templates.

I'm adding this second menu to the global context:

```
$context['custom-menu'] = new Timber\Menu( 'Custom Menu' );
```

and calling the menu in my index.php file.

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery();
$templates = array( 'index.twig' );
if ( is_home() ) {
    array_unshift( $templates, 'home.twig' );
}
Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

The header.twig file is included in the base.twig which is extended to index.twig. This includes all the header pieces.

```
{% include "partial/user-menu.twig" with {'custom-menu': custom-menu.get_items} %}
{% include "menu.twig" with {'menu': menu.get_items} %}
{% include "partial/sl_logo.twig" %}
{% include "partial/sl_search.twig" %}
```

The menu.twig is rendering just fine, but when I add the user-menu, it gives me the error at the top. When I remove `with {'custom-menu': custom-menu.get_items}` it gives me the error: `Object of class Timber\Menu could not be converted to int`

The user-menu.twig file looks like this:

```
    <ul>
    {% for item in custom-menu %}
        <li class="{{ item.classes | join(' ') }}">
            <a target="{{ item.target }}" href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
             {% include "user-menu.twig" with {'custom-menu': item.get_children} %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

The Documentation on the Timber Github repo suggests that you can add menus to the global context and simply add them when you get_context.

https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/docs/guides/menus.md

Can anyone help diagnose the issue?

Comment: Have you fixed your bug? I have the same issue of you. Thank you.

Comment: I was having trouble with the Timber Menu and finally found out that it didn't like the name containing a dash in it. I changed `custom-menu` to `custom_menu` and started working.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'll start with providing you the I'm using in the same situation.

In `functions.php` add

```
function add_to_context( $data ){
    //menu
    $data['menu_primary'] = new TimberMenu( 'primary' );
    $data['menu_footer'] = new TimberMenu( 'footer' );
    return $data;
}
```

Next use in desired place:

```
{% for item in menu_primary.get_items %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: +1 because this post made me realize I called TimberMenu with the menu id `Footer` instead of the menu location slug `footer` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus